# Evitar la notación científica al imprimir datos

Tags: c++

Tengo una duda estoy empezando a trabajar con c++ pero hay ciertas cantidades que son muy grandes y pues no me las muestra correctamente, adjuntaré dos imagenes
[image: estas son las variables en el código]

[image: esta es la imagen del error]

Comment: Por favor, [no publiques imagenes de código fuente o de consola](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21), publica directamente el texto de ambas.

Answer (score 5):

Ese es el comportamiento normal del tipo de datos en coma flotante `double`, se puede ver con el siguiente código:

```
double doble = 1900000.;
long long largo = 1900000ll;
std::cout
    << doble << '\n'
    << largo;
```

El código anterior muestra la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 1.9e+06
> 1900000
> ```

Como puedes ver, el valor en coma flotante (`double`) se muestra en notación científica, el valor entero (`long long`) se muestra con la notación tradicional. Si quieres evitar la notación científica puedes usar [`std::fixed`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed):

```
double doble = 1900000.;
long long largo = 1900000ll;
std::cout
    << std::fixed << doble << '\n'
//     ^^^^^^^^^^ <-- Notación tradicional
    << largo;
```

El código anterior muestra la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 1900000.000000
> 1900000
> ```

Si además quisieras eliminar los decimales<sup>1</sup>, podrías limitar la precisión a cero decimales:

```
double doble = 1900000.;
long long largo = 1900000ll;
std::cout
    << std::setprecision(0) << std::fixed << doble << '\n'
    << largo;
```

El código anterior muestra la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 1900000
> 1900000
> ```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU3LCsIwEDxnv2LBQ9uDUo@2tV/iJSaxLKSbkAcI4rfHPhDdw7Azw8wo74/KSp5KORArm7XBgVxMwch5hH9tlkx@BCBOOEviuoEXCO3y3RrUbsUrni/teqcehHU84Q4yTO5nWru4MemuUy4nEGIYcKPRJB@MokiO67bBr/6gp9Er21eWp7pxtQe37qUvmJQDY9vDu5QP)</kbd>.

---

- <sup>1</sup>Si no quieres decimales ¿Para qué usar un `double`?

Comment: Eh, le arreglas hasta el título a la pregunta pero le contestas sin dejarlo que haga una buena pregunta. ;)

Comment: @Alfabravo Ha llegado Papá Noël antes de tiempo. De todas maneras, con la corrección del título la pregunta pasa de ser descartable a ser pasable.

Comment: Sin duda alguna muchísimas gracias por sus correcciones, aún soy muy noob en éste mundo!